# Access Split Form Multiple Filters

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I have an Access database with a database of orders and the main form my users use is a split form view with the top being a nice GUI record viewer and the bottom is a datasheet list view of those records.

On the form, I have a textbox which users can type in numbers to get the order numbers to filer in the datasheet. The code is under `_Change()` so it is actively updating the datasheet with the matching order numbers.

The orders have several fields such as the following:

> Status: Pending, Open, Closed
>   Type: Vendor, Distributor, Contract

I created an Option group to allow users to select OPEN and then view only *open* orders or OPEN & Vendor to only view *open* and *vendor* orders. The code is under `_Click()` and accomplished with a Case statement and form filters for each case.

But my issue is, that if one of the options is selected and a user begins to type in an order number, the code for searching by order number will blank out the filter and ignore the filter set by the option group selection.

What would be the idea method of being able to select a case which filters out the records, and then search those records with an entry from the `textbox` search on the `form`?

I’m guessing I need to remove the part of the code in my textbox search that blanks out the filter but wanted to know if there is an idea method of doing this type of filter then search.

Thank you.

**Update 1**:

Added my code below. This is the combobox/textbox that users use to search for part numbers (PARTNO). They can enter any part of a part number and the filter will automatically filter as they type in a new character.

```
Private Sub cmbPARTNOSEARCH_Change()

If Nz(Me.cmbPARTNOSEARCH.Text) = "" Then
Me.cmbPARTNOSEARCH.Enabled = True
Me.Form.Filter = ""
Me.FilterOn = False

ElseIf Me.cmbPARTNOSEARCH.ListIndex <> -1 Then
If Me.cmbPARTNOSEARCH.ListIndex <> -1 Then
Me.Form.Filter = "[PARTNO] = '" & _
Replace(Me.cmbPARTNOSEARCH.Text, "'", "''") & "'"
Me.FilterOn = True

Else
Me.Form.Filter = "[PARTNO] Like '*" & _
Replace(Me.cmbPARTNOSEARCH.Text, "'", "''") & "*'"
Me.FilterOn = True

End If
End If

Me.cmbPARTNOSEARCH.SetFocus
Me.cmbPARTNOSEARCH.SelStart = Len(Me.cmbPARTNOSEARCH.Text)

End Sub
```

Comment: In order to help you, we need to see your existing code. Please edit your question and add it.

Comment: Code added. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a separate function that looks at all (both) filter controls, and builds and applies the filter from them.

Everything from your `_Change` sub except the last two lines go into that function, plus the `_Click` code from your option group.

The function looks at both filter controls, and builds a AND filter if both are set.
It is called from both event procedures.

**Edit:**

Here is a good example of a search form with multiple filter controls:
http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

In your case, since you are calling the function on `cmbPARTNOSEARCH_Change()`, you need to take into account whether the combobox has the focus (then use its `.Text` property) or not (then use its `.Value`).

You can use `Screen.ActiveControl` for that, or pass a parameter to the function to make that distinction.

---

Side note: in your code you have

```
ElseIf Me.cmbPARTNOSEARCH.ListIndex <> -1 Then
    If Me.cmbPARTNOSEARCH.ListIndex <> -1 Then
```

That doesn't make sense.